Can't Creating Pod Using Fabric8 from Existing Deployment Template
I'm currently working on a Java application where my goal is to create a new Pod as an instance of an existing Deployment, using the Fabric8 Kubernetes Client. My approach is to take a running Pod from an existing Deployment as a template, modify some parameters, and then create a new Pod based on those modifications. However, the new Pod doesn't start as expected.
Here's the code I'm working with:
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
            // Specify the namespace and deployment name
            String namespace = "demo-ns";
            String deploymentName = "DemoDeployment";

            Pod aDeploymentPod = client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).withLabel("app-name", deploymentName).list().getItems().get(0);

            // Read the existing deployment
            Resource<Deployment> deploymentResource = client.apps().deployments().inNamespace(namespace).withName(deploymentName);
            Deployment deployment = deploymentResource.get();
            Pod pod  = aDeploymentPod.toBuilder().build();
            pod.getSpec().getContainers().get(0).setArgs(Arrays.asList("arg1,arg2"));
            pod.getMetadata().getLabels().put("attr1","attr1Value");
            pod.getMetadata().setResourceVersion(null);
            pod.getMetadata().setName(null);
            pod.getMetadata().setUid(null);
            
            Pod createdPod = client.pods().inNamespace(namespace).resource(pod).create();
            System.out.println("Pod created: " + createdPod.getMetadata().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

The Pod seems to be created successfully as object, and a new name is assigned. However, it doesn’t actually start running. I don't find it in the running pods list
while executing kubectl get pod command
Any guidance on what might be causing this issue, or best practices for this approach, would be greatly appreciated! This is my first time using Fabric8 in this way, so any tips are welcome.
Thanks in advance!
